# UITextField - Next Button

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to I go from one textfield to the next with the next button?

Here is my code that will not work:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    if (theTextField == self.amountField) {
        [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    } else if (theTextField == self.businessField) {
        [self.memoField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992265/best-way-to-use-next-version-of-return-button-on-uitextfield-to-move-to-next-u

Answer (score 1):

Call `[textField resignFirstResponder];` before your first conditional

Answer (score 0):

there are many solutions but I prefer this one:

```
[self.firstTextField addTarget:self.secondTextField action:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
[self.secondTextField addTarget:self.thirdTextField action:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
```

just set it up in viewDidLoad