# How to navigate through textfields (Next / Done Buttons)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How can I navigate through all my text fields with the "Next" Button on the iPhone Keyboard?

The last text field should close the Keyboard.

I've setup the IB the Buttons (Next / Done) but now I'm stuck.

I implemented the textFieldShouldReturn action but now the Next and Done Buttons close the Keyboard.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer below. In my experience it is a better, more complete, solution than the answer typically given. I've no idea why anyone would give it a negative rating.

Comment: I have the similar issue but with Cordova, Phonegap 
Is there any ways to solve it?

Answer (score 593, accepted):

In Cocoa for Mac OS X, you have the next responder chain, where you can ask the text field what control should have focus next. This is what makes tabbing between text fields work. But since iOS devices do not have a keyboard, only touch, this concept has not survived the transition to Cocoa Touch.

This can be easily done anyway, with two assumptions:

1. All "tabbable" `UITextField`s are on the same parent view.
2. Their "tab-order" is defined by the tag property.

Assuming this you can override textFieldShouldReturn: as this:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField
{
  NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
  // Try to find next responder
  UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];
  if (nextResponder) {
    // Found next responder, so set it.
    [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
  } else {
    // Not found, so remove keyboard.
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
  }
  return NO; // We do not want UITextField to insert line-breaks.
}
```

Add some more code, and the assumptions can be ignored as well.

**Swift 4.0**

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let nextTag = textField.tag + 1
    // Try to find next responder
    let nextResponder = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(nextTag) as UIResponder!

    if nextResponder != nil {
        // Found next responder, so set it
        nextResponder?.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
        // Not found, so remove keyboard
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    return false
}
```

**If the superview of the text field will be a UITableViewCell then next responder will be**

```
let nextResponder = textField.superview?.superview?.superview?.viewWithTag(nextTag) as UIResponder!
```

Comment: Sometimes there is are "next" and "previous" buttons on top of the keyboard. At least in the browser.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, I want to clear up some misinformation in this post. On OS X, tab order is set up via NSView's setNextKeyView: (not setNextResponder:) method. The responder chain is separate from this: it's a hierarchy of responder objects that handle "untargeted" actions, e.g. actions sent to the first responder instead of directly to a controller object. The responder chain usually follows the view hierarchy, up to the window and its controller, and then the app delegate. Google "responder chain" for plenty of info.

Comment: The superview of the text field will be a `UITableViewCell`. You would need to access the associated `UITableView` and get the cell containing the text field you're looking for.

Comment: Don't forget to add the `UITextFieldDelegate` and set the textfields delegates.

Comment: I was trying this with next and done on the text fields but this does not work, @Sal how do I set the delegates exactly is that what I am missing besides the code above and just setting the return key as next on the storyboard view controller?

Comment: @JayImerman I'm facing the same problem currently. Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @Isuru, yes - look down, Michael Emmons answered his own post with a very elegant solution to subclass and create some very succinct code to control this.

Comment: I think the first rule is misleading. They should just have a parentView in common and that would work. They don't need to be at the same level in the view hierarchy.

Comment: How can I do the same in cordova/phonegap/jquery  hybrid project?

Comment: Friendly reminder to set the TAG option from the storyboard (in my case). You must manually set the TextFields tag in ascending order. (First is 0, second is 1 etc.) for this solution to work.

Comment: As @Sal has pointed out, do not forget to Control Drag all your text fields to the View Controller button and setting them as delegates. Nothing will happen until you do this. So if you did all of the above and it just wont jump to the next one, this might be your error.

Comment: I have 5 sections in my tableview. In each of sections there are certain number of rows in tableview. so how can I achieve textfield delegates working properly with "next" key.??

Comment: what did you write in the "nextTag" ? what to put there

Answer (score 172):

There is a *much* more elegant solution which blew me away the first time I saw it. Benefits:

- Closer to OSX textfield implementation where a textfield knows where the focus should go next
- Does not rely on setting or using tags -- which are, IMO fragile for this use case
- Can be extended to work with both `UITextField` and `UITextView` controls -- or any keyboard entry UI control
- Doesn't clutter your view controller with boilerplate UITextField delegate code
- Integrates nicely with IB and can be configured through the familiar option-drag-drop to connect outlets.

Create a UITextField subclass which has an `IBOutlet` property called nextField. Here's the header:

```
@interface SOTextField : UITextField

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nextField; 

@end
```

And here's the implementation:

```
@implementation SOTextField

@end
```

In your view controller, you'll create the `-textFieldShouldReturn:` delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if ([textField isKindOfClass:[SOTextField class]]) {
        UITextField *nextField = [(SOTextField *)textField nextField];

        if (nextField) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
                [nextField becomeFirstResponder];
            });
        }
        else {
            [textField resignFirstResponder];
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

In IB, change your UITextFields to use the `SOTextField` class. Next, also in IB, set the delegate for each of the 'SOTextFields'to 'File's Owner' (which is right where you put the code for the delegate method - textFieldShouldReturn). The beauty of this design is that now you can simply right-click on any textField and assign the nextField outlet to the next `SOTextField` object you want to be the next responder.

[image: Assigning nextField in IB]

Moreover, you can do cool things like loop the textFields so that after the last one loses focus, the first one will receive focus again.

This can easily be extended to automatically assign the `returnKeyType` of the `SOTextField` to a `UIReturnKeyNext` if there is a nextField assigned -- one less thing manually configure.

Comment: I think that it's easier to set tags than use this subclass. But it's an interesting alternative... thanks

Comment: I really like the IB integration over using tags -- particularly with the newer versions of Xcode which integrates IB nicely with he rest of the IDE -- and not having to clutter up my controller with boilerplate textField delegate code is a bonus.

Comment: Tags are easier, but this way is better, and more appropriate to a good OO design

Comment: I really like this solution, but I am using each text field in separate cell views in a `UITableView`.  Although I have `IBOutlet` properties on the view controller for each text field, it is not letting me link the `nextField` property to those properties on the File's Owner.  Any advice how I can make it work in this scenario?

Comment: @JayImerman IB will not allow you to connect outlets between cells. So, IB will be a no-go for this scenario. However, you could just hook up the nextField properties using code. `textField1.nextField = textField2; textField2.nextField = textField3;`, etc.

Comment: Why bother with dispatch_async at all? Won't textFieldShouldReturn only be called from the main thread anyway?

Comment: If you declare `nextField` as a `UIResponder` then it'll work even if the next control in line is not a text field (e.g. a `UITextView`).

Comment: To answer my own question: without the dispatch_async, the return key press ends up getting sent to the new field :-(

Comment: I don't know if this is the case in prior versions of IB, but I can verify that in a possible future version of Xcode that some people under NDA may or may not be using, IB will detect outlets declared in categories. So you don't even need to change the class.

Comment: Any chance this answer could be updated for newer versions of xcode and ios?

Comment: @memmons don't resign first -- just let the next field become the first responder. Resigning first leads to keyboard event notification cycle (though it's transparent to the user).

Comment: Extending the text field class just to make the keyboard work the way users expect a keyboard to work in any form field ever? Wow, Apple.

Answer (score 92):

Here's one without delegation:

```
tf1.addTarget(tf2, action: #selector(becomeFirstResponder), for: .editingDidEndOnExit)
tf2.addTarget(tf3, action: #selector(becomeFirstResponder), for: .editingDidEndOnExit)
```

ObjC:

```
[tf1 addTarget:tf2 action:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
[tf2 addTarget:tf3 action:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
```

Works using the (mostly unknown) `UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit` `UITextField` action.

You can also easily hook this up in the storyboard, so no delegation *or* code is required.

Edit: actually I cannot figure out how to hook this up in storyboard. `becomeFirstResponder` does not seem to be a offered action for this control-event, which is a pity. Still, you can hook all your textfields up to a single action in your ViewController which then determines which textField to `becomeFirstResponder` based on the sender (though then it is not as elegant as the above programmatic solution so IMO do it with the above code in `viewDidLoad`).

Comment: Very simple and effective solution. The last one in chain can even trigger e.g. `[tfN addTarget:self action:@selector(loginButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];`. Thanks @mxcl.

Comment: How would you do this in storyboard?

Comment: This is probably the best answer here.

Comment: This worked for me perfectly even in Swift 2. This is a much simpler and quicker solution than adding in delegates.

Comment: This is really the best solution I've found. No need for ekstra delegates or anything smart. Most simple, and best solution!

Comment: Swift 4: txtFirstname.addTarget(txtLastname, action: 
#selector(becomeFirstResponder), for: UIControlEvents.editingDidEndOnExit)

Comment: In `Swift4` the last text field can be implemented as: textfieldLast.addTarget(textfieldLast, action: #selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), for: .editingDidEndOnExit)

Comment: Such a simple, declarative and elegant solution !

Comment: Like @msrdjan said it can trigger the login button or if you have other components like a switch to accept terms and conditions, just call `resignFirstResponder` on itself

Comment: When we set delegate and using shouldChangeCharactersInRange: method this is not working. Anybody any idea?

Answer (score 78):

Here is my solution for this problem.

To solve this (and because I hate relying on tags to do stuff) I decided to add a custom property to the UITextField object. In other words I created a category on UITextField like this :

***UITextField+Extended.h***

```
@interface UITextField (Extended)

@property(retain, nonatomic)UITextField* nextTextField;

@end
```

***UITextField+Extended.m***

```
#import "UITextField+Extended.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static char defaultHashKey;

@implementation UITextField (Extended)

- (UITextField*) nextTextField { 
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &defaultHashKey); 
}

- (void) setNextTextField:(UITextField *)nextTextField{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &defaultHashKey, nextTextField, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC); 
}

@end
```

Now, here is how I use it :

```
UITextField *textField1 = ...init your textfield
UITextField *textField2 = ...init your textfield
UITextField *textField3 = ...init your textfield

textField1.nextTextField = textField2;
textField2.nextTextField = textField3;
textField3.nextTextField = nil;
```

And implement the textFieldShouldReturn method :

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {

    UITextField *next = theTextField.nextTextField;
    if (next) {
        [next becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }

    return NO; 
}
```

I now have kind of a linked list of UITextField, each one knowing who's next in the line.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: This is the best solution and should be chosen as the answer.

Comment: This solution worked for me, only thing I changed was making the nextTextField and IBOutlet so I could set up chaining from within my Storyboard.

Comment: If I could save favorite answers, this would be one of them.  Thanks for the clean solution!

Comment: Note that if IB is your thing, you can also set these properties as IBOutlets. . be careful with name collisions - Apple may eventually add this to UIResponder.

Comment: Is this solution compatible with interface builder? I mean can it use IBOutlets and storyboard references instead of setting the nextTextField programmatically? IB doesn't seem to allow you to set the UITextField class to a category.

Comment: This solution is accurate but is not storyboard compatible because you cannot set the class of a UITextField to be a category (yet?).

Comment: Best approach when using textfields inside a tableview. Thx!

Comment: why do we need to use "objc_getAssociatedObject" and "objc_setAssociatedObject" methods here ? Is there any specific importance to use it?

Comment: I am having a bit of a challenge with this.  I'll be the first to admit I don't understand the responder mechanism.  I am using an XIB to define the UIView.  I added IBOutlet to the property, so that I can drag the nextTextField to do the association visually. When I run the app, I don't get any response.  Perhaps @JasperBlues can provide some insight how to make the IBOutlet change.

Answer (score 50):

A swift extension that applies mxcl's answer to make this particularly easy (adapted to swift 2.3 by Traveler):

```
extension UITextField {
    class func connectFields(fields:[UITextField]) -> Void {
        guard let last = fields.last else {
            return
        }
        for i in 0 ..< fields.count - 1 {
            fields[i].returnKeyType = .Next
            fields[i].addTarget(fields[i+1], action: "becomeFirstResponder", forControlEvents: .EditingDidEndOnExit)
        }
        last.returnKeyType = .Done
        last.addTarget(last, action: #selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), forControlEvents: .EditingDidEndOnExit)
    }
}
```

It's easy to use:

```
UITextField.connectFields([field1, field2, field3])
```

The extension will set the return button to "Next" for all but the last field and to "Done" for the last field, and shift focus / dismiss the keyboard when these are tapped.

**Swift < 2.3**

```
extension UITextField {
    class func connectFields(fields:[UITextField]) -> Void {
        guard let last = fields.last else {
            return
        }
        for var i = 0; i < fields.count - 1; i += 1 {
            fields[i].returnKeyType = .Next
            fields[i].addTarget(fields[i+1], action: "becomeFirstResponder", forControlEvents: .EditingDidEndOnExit)
        }
        last.returnKeyType = .Done
        last.addTarget(last, action: "resignFirstResponder", forControlEvents: .EditingDidEndOnExit)
    }
}
```

**SWIFT 3:**
use like this -

```
UITextField.connectFields(fields: [field1, field2])

Extension:
    extension UITextField {
        class func connectFields(fields:[UITextField]) -> Void {
            guard let last = fields.last else {
                return
            }
            for i in 0 ..< fields.count - 1 {
                fields[i].returnKeyType = .next
                fields[i].addTarget(fields[i+1], action: #selector(UIResponder.becomeFirstResponder), for: .editingDidEndOnExit)
            }
            last.returnKeyType = .go
            last.addTarget(last, action: #selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), for: .editingDidEndOnExit)
        }
    }
```

Comment: BTW, if you want to then have Done perform an action, you can just have your View Controller conform to `UITextFieldDelegate`, and implement `func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField)`.  Just return out early if `textField != field3`.

Answer (score 25):

A more consistent and robust way is to use [NextResponderTextField](https://github.com/mohamede1945/NextResponderTextField)
You can configure it totally from interface builder with no need for setting the delegate or using `view.tag`.

All you need to do is

1. Set the class type of your `UITextField` to be `NextResponderTextField` 
   [image]
2. Then set the outlet of the `nextResponderField` to point to the next responder it can be anything `UITextField` or any `UIResponder` subclass. It can be also a UIButton and the library is smart enough to trigger the `TouchUpInside` event of the button only if it's enabled.
   [image]
   [image]

Here is the library in action:

[image]

Comment: Yes. Works really well with Swift 3.1, very elegant solution, just how IB should be working out of the box.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the question.

Comment: NextResponderTextField worked for me.  It was quick and easy to use, just one swift file, and did exactly what I needed with no fuss.

Comment: This works great! Note: I had to change the Return key manually to get it to display "Next" and "Done" like in the example.

Answer (score 14):

I like the OO solutions that have already been suggested by Anth0 and Answerbot. However, I was working on a quick and small POC, so I didn't want to clutter things with subclasses and categories.

Another simple solution is to create an NSArray of fields and lookup the next field when you press next. Not an OO solution, but quick, simple, and easy to implement. Also, you can see and modify the ordering at a glance.

Here's my code (built upon other answers in this thread):

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *fieldArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    fieldArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: firstField, secondField, thirdField, nil];
}

- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *) textField {
    BOOL didResign = [textField resignFirstResponder];
    if (!didResign) return NO;

    NSUInteger index = [self.fieldArray indexOfObject:textField];
    if (index == NSNotFound || index + 1 == fieldArray.count) return NO;

    id nextField = [fieldArray objectAtIndex:index + 1];
    activeField = nextField;
    [nextField becomeFirstResponder];

    return NO;
}
```

- I always return NO because I don't want a line break inserted. Just thought I'd point that out since when I returned YES it would automatically exit the subsequent fields or insert a line break in my TextView. It took me a bit of time to figure that out.
- activeField keeps track of the active field in case scrolling is necessary to unobscure the field from the keyboard. If you have similar code, make sure you assign the activeField before changing the first responder. Changing first responder is immediate and will fire the KeyboardWasShown event immediately.

Comment: Nice! Simple and the code is all in one model. AnthO's is very nice as well.

Comment: Keep in mind that you're running the risk of retain cycles with this code. Your fieldArray is converting the weak references used in all of your IBOutlets to strong references in the array itself.

Answer (score 12):

Here is an implementation of tabbing using a category on UIControl. This solution has all of the advantages of the methods from Michael and Anth0, but works for all UIControls, not just `UITextField`s. It also works seamlessly with Interface Builder and storyboards.

Source and sample app: [GitHub repository for UIControlsWithTabbing](https://github.com/picciano/UIControlsWithTabbing)

Usage:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField transferFirstResponderToNextControl];
    return NO;
}
```

[image: Assigning nextControl in Interface Builder]

Header:

```
//
// UIControl+NextControl.h
// UIControlsWithTabbing
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIControl (NextControl)

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIControl *nextControl;

- (BOOL)transferFirstResponderToNextControl;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "UIControl+NextControl.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static char defaultHashKey;

@implementation UIControl (NextControl)

- (UIControl *)nextControl
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &defaultHashKey);
}

- (void)setNextControl:(UIControl *)nextControl
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &defaultHashKey, nextControl, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (BOOL)transferFirstResponderToNextControl
{
    if (self.nextControl)
    {
        [self.nextControl becomeFirstResponder];

        return YES;
    }

    [self resignFirstResponder];

    return NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: Sometimes the next widget is not a control i.e. UITextView and you may wish to tab there also. Consider changing the type from UITextField to UIResponder.

Comment: Works great and with fantastic documentation. I wish that i scroll down into this question several hours ago. :)

Answer (score 10):

I have tried many codes and finally, this worked for me in **Swift 3.0 Latest [March 2017]**

The `ViewController` class should be inherited the `UITextFieldDelegate` for making this code working.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate
```

Add the Text field with the Proper Tag number and this tag number is used to take the control to appropriate text field based on incremental tag number assigned to it.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    userNameTextField.delegate = self
    userNameTextField.tag = 0
    userNameTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.next
    passwordTextField.delegate = self
    passwordTextField.tag = 1
    passwordTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.go
}
```

In the above code, the `returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.next` where will make the Key pad return key to display as `Next` you also have other options as `Join/Go` etc, based on your application change the values.

This  `textFieldShouldReturn` is a method of  UITextFieldDelegate controlled and here we have next field selection based on the Tag value incrementation

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if let nextField = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) as? UITextField {
        nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true;
    }
    return false
 }
```

Comment: This works, except if the input field is `UITextView`. Any idea how to do this in combination?

Comment: @T9b What you need exactly? what type control are you using in your app?

Comment: There are two types of text inputs, the first is `UITextField` (enter single line of text), the other is `UITextView` (enter multiple lines of text). `UITextView` obviously does not respond to this code but it can be used in forms.

Comment: Yes this part of code for UITextField only and have you tried modifying the event for the UITextView?

Answer (score 9):

After you exit from one text field, you call [otherTextField becomeFirstResponder] and the next field gets focus.

This can actually be a tricky problem to deal with since often you'll also want to scroll the screen or otherwise adjust the position of the text field so it's easy to see when editing.  Just make sure to do a lot of testing with coming into and out of the text fields in different ways and also leaving early (always give the user an option to dismiss the keyboard instead of going to the next field, usually with "Done" in the nav bar)

Answer (score 9):

```
 -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [[self.view viewWithTag:textField.tag+1] becomeFirstResponder];
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: You should not use tags for this purpose.

Answer (score 8):

I am surprised by how many answers here fail to understand one simple concept: navigating through controls in your app is not something the views themselves should do. It's the **controller**'s job to decide which control to make the next first responder.

Also most answers only applied to navigating forward, but users may also want to go backwards.

So here's what I've come up with. Your form should be managed by a view controller, and view controllers are part of the responder chain. So you're perfectly free to implement the following methods:

```
#pragma mark - Key Commands

- (NSArray *)keyCommands
{
    static NSArray *commands;

    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        UIKeyCommand *const forward = [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"\t" modifierFlags:0 action:@selector(tabForward:)];
        UIKeyCommand *const backward = [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"\t" modifierFlags:UIKeyModifierShift action:@selector(tabBackward:)];

        commands = @[forward, backward];
    });

    return commands;
}

- (void)tabForward:(UIKeyCommand *)command
{
    NSArray *const controls = self.controls;
    UIResponder *firstResponder = nil;

    for (UIResponder *const responder in controls) {
        if (firstResponder != nil && responder.canBecomeFirstResponder) {
            [responder becomeFirstResponder]; return;
        }
        else if (responder.isFirstResponder) {
            firstResponder = responder;
        }
    }

    [controls.firstObject becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)tabBackward:(UIKeyCommand *)command
{
    NSArray *const controls = self.controls;
    UIResponder *firstResponder = nil;

    for (UIResponder *const responder in controls.reverseObjectEnumerator) {
        if (firstResponder != nil && responder.canBecomeFirstResponder) {
            [responder becomeFirstResponder]; return;
        }
        else if (responder.isFirstResponder) {
            firstResponder = responder;
        }
    }

    [controls.lastObject becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Additional logic for scrolling offscreen responders visible beforehand may apply.

Another advantage of this approach is that you don't need to subclass all kinds of controls you may want to display (like `UITextField`s) but can instead manage the logic at controller level, where, let's be honest, is *the right place* to do so.

Comment: I find your answer of the most relevance, but I've noticed something funny that perhaps you can clear up.  When using UITextFields that are not being managed by a UIViewController, pressing the tab key will make the next UITextField the first responder by default.  However, when each is managed by a VC, this isn't true.  My VC's aren't doing anything, but the built in tabbing functionality is gone.  I've noticed that keyCommands of the VC ends up being added to the responder chain of the view.  This leads me to believe that if you're using a VC, it's mandatory to implement keyCommands.

Answer (score 7):

A very easy method for dismissing the keyboard when the 'Done' button is pressed is:

Create a new IBAction in the header

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender;
```

In the implementation file (.m file) add the following method:

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender 
{ 
  [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Then, when you come to link the IBAction to the textfield - link to the 'Did End On Exit' event.

Comment: You're welcome, it doesn't navigate through the text fields but it does close the keyboard and allow you to select another field.

Answer (score 7):

First set keyboard return key in xib, otherwise you can write code in `viewdidload`:

```
passWord.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField == eMail) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [userName becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    if (textField==userName) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [passWord becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    if (textField==passWord) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [country becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    if (textField==country) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If someone wants like this. I think this is the closest to the requirements asked for in question

[image]

Here is how I have implemented this one

Add accessory view for each text field for which you want the setup, using

```
func setAccessoryViewFor(textField : UITextField)    {
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = .default
    toolBar.isTranslucent = true
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    // Adds the buttons

    // Add previousButton
    let prevButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "<", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(previousPressed(sender:)))
    prevButton.tag = textField.tag
    if getPreviousResponderFor(tag: textField.tag) == nil {
        prevButton.isEnabled = false
    }

    // Add nextButton
    let nextButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: ">", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(nextPressed(sender:)))
    nextButton.tag = textField.tag
    if getNextResponderFor(tag: textField.tag) == nil {
        nextButton.title = "Done"
    }

    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    toolBar.setItems([prevButton,spaceButton,nextButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}
```

Use following functions to handle taps

```
func nextPressed(sender : UIBarButtonItem) {
    if let nextResponder = getNextResponderFor(tag: sender.tag) {
        nextResponder.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

}

func previousPressed(sender : UIBarButtonItem) {
    if let previousResponder = getPreviousResponderFor(tag : sender.tag)  {
        previousResponder.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}

func getNextResponderFor(tag : Int) -> UITextField? {
    return self.view.viewWithTag(tag + 1) as? UITextField
}

func getPreviousResponderFor(tag : Int) -> UITextField? {
    return self.view.viewWithTag(tag - 1) as? UITextField
}
```

You will need to give the textFields tags in sequence in which you want the next/prev button to respond.

Answer (score 5):

Solution in Swift 3.1, After connecting your textfields IBOutlets set your textfields delegate in viewDidLoad, And then navigate your action in textFieldShouldReturn

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var phoneTextField: UITextField!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.passwordTextField.delegate = self
            self.phoneTextField.delegate = self
            // Set your return type
            self.phoneTextField.returnKeyType = .next
            self.passwordTextField.returnKeyType = .done
        }

        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
            if textField == self.phoneTextField {
                self.passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
            }else if textField == self.passwordTextField{
                // Call login api
                self.login()
            }
            return true
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Hi to everyone please see [this one](http://www.randomsequence.com/articles/adding-a-toolbar-with-next-previous-above-uitextfield-keyboard-iphone/)

```
- (void)nextPrevious:(id)sender
{

  UIView *responder = [self.view findFirstResponder];   

  if (nil == responder || ![responder isKindOfClass:[GroupTextField class]]) {
    return;
  }

  switch([(UISegmentedControl *)sender selectedSegmentIndex]) {
    case 0:
      // previous
      if (nil != ((GroupTextField *)responder).previousControl) {
        [((GroupTextField *)responder).previousControl becomeFirstResponder];
        DebugLog(@"currentControl: %i previousControl: %i",((GroupTextField *)responder).tag,((GroupTextField *)responder).previousControl.tag);
      }
      break;
    case 1:
      // next
      if (nil != ((GroupTextField *)responder).nextControl) {
        [((GroupTextField *)responder).nextControl becomeFirstResponder];
        DebugLog(@"currentControl: %i nextControl: %i",((GroupTextField *)responder).tag,((GroupTextField *)responder).nextControl.tag);
      }     
      break;    
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of UIView *responder it'd be more accurate to use UIRespoder *responder

Answer (score 4):

I have added to PeyloW's answer in case you're looking to implement a previous/next button functionality:

```
- (IBAction)moveThroughTextFields:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender 
{
    NSInteger nextTag;
    UITextView *currentTextField = [self.view findFirstResponderAndReturn];

    if (currentTextField != nil) {
        // I assigned tags to the buttons.  0 represent prev & 1 represents next
        if (sender.tag == 0) {
            nextTag = currentTextField.tag - 1;

        } else if (sender.tag == 1) {
            nextTag = currentTextField.tag + 1;
        }
    }
    // Try to find next responder
    UIResponder* nextResponder = [self.view viewWithTag:nextTag];
    if (nextResponder) {
        // Found next responder, so set it.
        // I added the resign here in case there's different keyboards in place.
        [currentTextField resignFirstResponder];
        [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        // Not found, so remove keyboard.
        [currentTextField resignFirstResponder];

    }
}
```

Where you subclass the UIView like this:

```
@implementation UIView (FindAndReturnFirstResponder)
- (UITextView *)findFirstResponderAndReturn
{
    for (UITextView *subView in self.subviews) {
        if (subView.isFirstResponder){
            return subView;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried to solve this problem using a more sophisticated approach based on assigning each cell (or `UITextField`) in a `UITableView` a unique tag value that can be later retrieved:
[activate-next-uitextfield-in-uitableview-ios](http://blog.encomiabile.it/2013/02/08/how-to-activate-next-uitextfield-in-uitableview-ios/)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

I've just created new Pod when dealing with this stuff [GNTextFieldsCollectionManager](https://github.com/jakubknejzlik/GNTextFieldsCollectionManager). It automatically handles next/last textField problem and is very easy to use:

```
[[GNTextFieldsCollectionManager alloc] initWithView:self.view];
```

Grabs all textfields sorted by appearing in view hierarchy (or by tags), or you can specify your own array of textFields.

Answer (score 4):

A safer and more direct way, assuming:

- the text field delegates are set to your view controller
- all of the text fields are subviews of the same view
- the text fields have tags in the order you want to progress (e.g., textField2.tag = 2, textField3.tag = 3, etc.)
- moving to the next text field will happen when you tap the *return* button on the keyboard (you can change this to *next*, *done*, etc.)
- you want the keyboard to dismiss after the last text field

**Swift 4.1:**

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        let nextTag = textField.tag + 1
        guard let nextTextField = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(nextTag) else {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }

    nextTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

    return false

    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, perfect solution!.

Answer (score 3):

I rather prefer to:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIView) NSArray *inputFields;
@end
```

In the NIB file I hook the textFields in the desired order into this inputFields array. After that I do a simple test for the index of the UITextField that reports that the user tapped return:

```
// for UITextField
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField {
    NSUInteger index = [_inputFields indexOfObject:textField];
    index++;
    if (index < _inputFields.count) {
        UIView *v = [_inputFields objectAtIndex:index];
        [v becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    return NO;
}

// for UITextView
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView*)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString*)text {
    if ([@"\n" isEqualToString:text]) {
        NSUInteger index = [_inputFields indexOfObject:textView];
        index++;
        if (index < _inputFields.count) {
            UIView *v = [_inputFields objectAtIndex:index];
            [v becomeFirstResponder];
        } else {
            [self.view endEditing:YES];
        }
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    txt_Input = [[ UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 150, 30)];
    txt_Input.tag = indexPath.row+1;
    [self.array_Textfields addObject:txt_Input]; // Initialize mutable array in ViewDidLoad
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

    int tag = ( int) textField.tag ;
    UITextField * txt = [  self.array_Textfields objectAtIndex:tag ] ;
    [ txt becomeFirstResponder] ;
    return YES ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had about 10+ UITextField in my story board and the way I enabled next functionality was by creating an array of UITextField and making the next UITextField the firstResponder. Here's the implementation file:

```
#import "RegistrationTableViewController.h"

@interface RegistrationTableViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *fullNameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *addressTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *address2TextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *cityTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *zipCodeTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *urlTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *emailTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *confirmPWTextField;

@end
NSArray *uiTextFieldArray;
@implementation RegistrationTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"view did load");
    uiTextFieldArray = @[self.fullNameTextField,self.addressTextField,self.address2TextField,self.cityTextField,self.zipCodeTextField,self.urlTextField,self.usernameTextField,self.emailTextField,self.passwordTextField,self.confirmPWTextField];
    for(UITextField *myField in uiTextFieldArray){
        myField.delegate = self;
    }


}
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    long index = [uiTextFieldArray indexOfObject:textField];
    NSLog(@"%ld",index);
    if(index < (uiTextFieldArray.count - 1)){
        [uiTextFieldArray[++index] becomeFirstResponder];
    }else{
        [uiTextFieldArray[index] resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me in Xamarin.iOS / Monotouch.
Change the keyboard button to Next, pass the control to the next UITextField and hide the keyboard after the last UITextField.

```
private void SetShouldReturnDelegates(IEnumerable<UIView> subViewsToScout )
{
  foreach (var item in subViewsToScout.Where(item => item.GetType() == typeof (UITextField)))
  {
    (item as UITextField).ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Next;
    (item as UITextField).ShouldReturn += (textField) =>
    {
        nint nextTag = textField.Tag + 1;
        var nextResponder = textField.Superview.ViewWithTag(nextTag);
        if (null != nextResponder)
            nextResponder.BecomeFirstResponder();
        else
            textField.Superview.EndEditing(true); 
            //You could also use textField.ResignFirstResponder(); 

        return false; // We do not want UITextField to insert line-breaks.
    };
  }
}
```

Inside the **ViewDidLoad** you'll have:

If your TextFields haven't a Tag set it now:

```
txtField1.Tag = 0;
txtField2.Tag = 1;
txtField3.Tag = 2;
//...
```

and just the call

```
SetShouldReturnDelegates(yourViewWithTxtFields.Subviews.ToList());
//If you are not sure of which view contains your fields you can also call it in a safer way:
SetShouldReturnDelegates(txtField1.Superview.Subviews.ToList());
//You can also reuse the same method with different containerViews in case your UITextField are under different views.
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple solution in swift, with no tag using, no storyboard tricks...

Just use this extension :

```
extension UITextField{

    func nextTextFieldField() -> UITextField?{
        //field to return
        var returnField : UITextField?
        if self.superview != nil{
            //for each view in superview
            for (_, view) in self.superview!.subviews.enumerate(){
                //if subview is a text's field
                if view.isKindOfClass(UITextField){
                    //cast curent view as text field
                    let currentTextField = view as! UITextField
                    //if text field is after the current one
                    if currentTextField.frame.origin.y > self.frame.origin.y{
                        //if there is no text field to return already
                        if returnField == nil {
                            //set as default return
                            returnField = currentTextField
                        }
                            //else if this this less far than the other
                        else if currentTextField.frame.origin.y < returnField!.frame.origin.y{
                            //this is the field to return
                            returnField = currentTextField
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //end of the mdethod
        return returnField
    }

}
```

And call it like this (for example) with your textfield delegate:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    textField.nextTextFieldField()?.becomeFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Comment: One comment on this is that your method assumes all fields are stacked vertically in a single superview. It doesn't allow for grouped fields and doesn't work when textfields may be side-by-side. The later is especially important these days when one uses size classes to rearrange forms for horizontal views and when forms are displayed on tablets.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Swift 3 version of **Anth0**'s answer. I'm posting it here to help any swift developers in wanting to take advantage of his great answer! I took the liberty of adding a return key type of "Next" when you set the associated object.

```
extension UITextField {

  @nonobjc static var NextHashKey: UniChar = 0

  var nextTextField: UITextField? {
    get {
      return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, 
        &UITextField.NextHashKey) as? UITextField
    }
    set(next) {
     self.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.next
     objc_setAssociatedObject(self,
      &UITextField.NextHashKey,next,.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
    }
  }
}
```

Here is another extension that shows a possibility of using the above code to cycle through a list of UITextFields.

```
extension UIViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
 public func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
   guard let next = textField.nextTextField else {
     textField.resignFirstResponder()
     return true
   }

    next.becomeFirstResponder()
    return false
  }
}
```

And then in your ViewController or wherever, you can setup your textfields like so...

```
@IBOutlet fileprivate weak var textfield1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet fileprivate weak var textfield2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet fileprivate weak var textfield3: UITextField!

...

[textfield1, textfield2, textfield3].forEach{ $0?.delegate = self }

textfield1.nextTextField = textfield2
textfield2.nextTextField = textfield3
// We don't assign a nextTextField to textfield3 because we want 
// textfield3 to be the last one and resignFirstResponder when 
// the return button on the soft keyboard is tapped.
```

Answer (score 2):

in textFieldShouldReturn you should check that the textfield you are currently on is not the last one when they click next and if its n ot dont dismiss the keyboard..

Comment: Hey,

ok this works, but how can i jump to the next textfield with the "Next" Button?

Answer (score 2):

Without usings tags and without adding a property for nextField/nextTextField, you can try this to emulate TAB, where "testInput" is your current active field:

```
if ([textInput isFirstResponder])
    [textInput.superview.subviews enumerateObjectsAtIndexes:
     [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:
      NSMakeRange([textInput.superview.subviews indexOfObject:textInput]+1,
                  [textInput.superview.subviews count]-[textInput.superview.subviews indexOfObject:textInput]-1)]
                                                    options:0 usingBlock:^(UIView *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                                                        *stop = !obj.hidden && [obj becomeFirstResponder];
                                                    }];
if ([textInput isFirstResponder])
    [textInput.superview.subviews enumerateObjectsAtIndexes:
     [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:
      NSMakeRange(0,
                  [textInput.superview.subviews indexOfObject:textInput])]
                                                    options:0 usingBlock:^(UIView *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                                                        *stop = !obj.hidden && [obj becomeFirstResponder];
                                                    }];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post, but has a high page rank so I'll chime in with my solution.

I had a similar issue and ended up creating a subclass of `UIToolbar` to manage the next/previous/done functionality in a dynamic tableView with sections: https://github.com/jday001/DataEntryToolbar

You set the toolbar as inputAccessoryView of your text fields and add them to its dictionary. This allows you to cycle through them forwards and backwards, even with dynamic content. There are delegate methods if you want to trigger your own functionality when textField navigation happens, but you don't have to deal with managing any tags or first responder status.

There are code snippets & an example app at the GitHub link to help with the implementation details. You will need your own data model to keep track of the values inside the fields.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using Michael G. Emmons' answer for about a year now, works great. I did notice recently that calling resignFirstResponder and then becomeFirstResponder immediately can cause the keyboard to "glitch", disappearing and then appearing immediately. I changed his version slightly to skip the resignFirstResponder if the nextField is available.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{ 

    if ([textField isKindOfClass:[NRTextField class]])
    {
        NRTextField *nText = (NRTextField*)textField;
        if ([nText nextField] != nil){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                           ^ { [[nText nextField] becomeFirstResponder]; });

        }
        else{
            [textField resignFirstResponder];
        }
    }
    else{
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }

    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use IQKeyboardManager library to do this. it handle every thing, you don't need any additional setup.IQKeyboardManager is available through CocoaPods, to install it simply add the following line to your Podfile:

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
```

or
Just drag and drop IQKeyBoardManager directory from demo project to your project. That's it.
you can find IQKeyBoardManager directory from https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a dynamic solution for navigating through Responders in a view hierarchy. The idea is, to search the whole hierarchy for the next possible responder, forwards or backwards as needed.

UIView Extension for searching:

UIView+Cat.h

```
- (UIResponder *)getNextFirstResponder;
- (UIResponder *)getPreviousFirstResponder;
```

UIView+Cat.m

```
- (UIResponder *)getPreviousFirstResponder {
    if (!self.superview) {
        return nil;
    }
    
    BOOL hasreachedself = NO;
    for (NSInteger i = self.superview.subviews.count-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        UIView *v = [self.superview.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        if (v == self) {
            hasreachedself = YES;
            continue;
        }
        if (!hasreachedself) continue;
        
        if ([v canBecomeFirstResponder] && !v.hidden) {
            return v;
        }
        UIResponder *subResponder = [self getNextFirstResponderInView:v];
        if (subResponder) {
            return subResponder;
        }
    }
    
    //search hierachicaly in superviews
    return [self.superview getPreviousFirstResponder];
}

- (UIResponder *)getNextFirstResponder {
    if (!self.superview) {
        return nil;
    }
    
    BOOL hasreachedself = NO;
    for (UIView *v in self.superview.subviews) {
        if (v == self) {
            hasreachedself = YES;
            continue;
        }
        if (!hasreachedself) continue;
        
        if ([v canBecomeFirstResponder] && !v.hidden) {
            return v;
        }
        UIResponder *subResponder = [self getNextFirstResponderInView:v];
        if (subResponder) {
            return subResponder;
        }
    }
    
    //search hierachicaly in superviews
    return [self.superview getNextFirstResponder];
}

- (UIResponder *)getNextFirstResponderInView:(UIView *)view {
    if ([view canBecomeFirstResponder] && !view.hidden) {
        return view;
    }
    for (UIView *v in view.subviews) {
        UIResponder *subResponder = [self getNextFirstResponderInView:v];
        if (subResponder) {
            return subResponder;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Usage: Add UIToolbar to UITextField / UITextView (in category or subclass):

```
- (void)addToolbarInputAccessoryView {
    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    UIBarButtonItem *prev = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"chevron.up"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(moveToPreviousFirstResponder)];
    UIBarButtonItem *next = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"chevron.down"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(moveToNextFirstResponder)];
    UIBarButtonItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *done = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
    toolbar.items = @[prev, next, space, done];
    
    if ([[UITextField appearance] keyboardAppearance] == UIKeyboardAppearanceDark) {
        toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
        toolbar.translucent = YES;
        [toolbar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [toolbar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
    
    [toolbar sizeToFit];
    
    self.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
}

- (void)hideKeyboard {
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)moveToNextFirstResponder {
    UIResponder *next = [self getNextFirstResponder];
    if (next) {
        [next becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else {
        [self resignFirstResponder];
    }
}

- (void)moveToPreviousFirstResponder {
    UIResponder *prev = [self getPreviousFirstResponder];
    if (prev) {
        [prev becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else {
        [self resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 Solution**, using ordered array of `UITextField's`

```
func nextTextField() {
    let textFields = // Your textfields array

    for i in 0 ..< textFields.count{
        if let textfield = textFields[i], textfield.isFirstResponder{
            textfield.resignFirstResponder()
            if i+1 < textFields.count, let nextextfield = textFields[i+1]{
                nextextfield.becomeFirstResponder()
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Swift 4 for mxcl answer:

```
txtFirstname.addTarget(txtLastname, action: 
#selector(becomeFirstResponder), for: UIControlEvents.editingDidEndOnExit)
```