# iOS app "next" key won't go to the next text field

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, first-responder

I have a simple scene (using storyboard in IB) with a Username and Password text box.  I've set the keyboard to close when you are on the Password text field but can't get the next(return) button to work on the Username to switch the focus (or First Responder) to the Password text box.

I'm closing the keyboard while on the Password text field like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
if (theTextField == self.textPassword) {
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
return YES;
}
```

I know it is something similar to this but just can't nail it down.

Comment: add below library and thats it  https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The return key doesn't do anything special in a text field by default.  You need to explicitly change the first responder:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    if (theTextField == self.textPassword) {
        [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    } else if (theTextField == self.textUsername) {
        [self.textPassword becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the same for swift?

Comment: @RaphaelRoyer-Rivard you should set the `delegate` of the `UITextField` to the viewcontroller (or whatever class this code is added to)

Comment: @vrwin's comment should be part of the answer, this is step 1 to this answer working.

Answer (score 42):

I use this code that allows me to control the form behavior in the **storyboard**:

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    if(textField.returnKeyType==UIReturnKeyNext) {
        UIView *next = [[textField superview] viewWithTag:textField.tag+1];
        [next becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField.returnKeyType==UIReturnKeyDone) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

All you need is to assign the order value as `tag`, and `returnkey` according to **Next** or **Done** on each input control.

Comment: Best answer among all !!

Comment: So how would you set tags for the text fields?

Comment: Is it as simple as exampleField.tag = 1; ?

Comment: Yes, just set tag property. Use tags to keep editing order, and if you use storyboards is still easier.

Comment: This also should be accepted as answer ,,,,,, best ways to navigate through UITextFiled

Comment: Brilliant idea!

Answer (score 11):

for those who want to use Swift language:

```
class MyClass: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var text1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var text2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var text3: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    text1.delegate = self
    text2.delegate = self
    text3.delegate = self


}

//....

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
    if textField == self.text1 {
        self.text2.becomeFirstResponder()
    }else if textField == self.text2{
        self.text3.becomeFirstResponder()
    }else{
        self.text1.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
 }

 //...
```

}

:-)

Answer (score 9):

You have to add the UITextFieldDelegate in the header-file.
Then you have to set

```
theTextField.delegate = self;
```

in the viewDidLoad-method.
After that you can go on with

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    if (theTextField == self.textPassword) {
        [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    } else if (theTextField == self.textUsername) {
        [self.textPassword becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Many solutions to this problem exist. See the responses posted to this question: [How to navigate through textfields (Next / Done Buttons)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347779/how-to-navigate-through-textfields-next-done-buttons).

Read more in the [UIResponder Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you would put:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    if (theTextField == self.textPassword) {
        [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    } else if (theTextField == self.usernameField) {
        [self.textPassword becomeFirstResponder];
    }
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this subclass of UITextfield that dynamically change the UIReturnKey according to text/string condition, and then perform your continuation action in the textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField delegate

```
if (textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyNext)

https://github.com/codeinteractiveapps/OBReturnKeyTextField
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an issue that password textfield get focus and then lose focus immediately. At last I found that we'd better return NO in function textFieldShouldReturn:. If we return YES, the text field will get a insertText: call. Then it will lose focus. Don't know the reason.

I have created a new question for this issue: [UITextField get focus and then lose focus immediately due to return YES in textFieldShouldReturn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755870/uitextfield-get-focus-and-then-lose-focus-immediately-due-to-return-yes-in-textf)

If anyone knows the reason, please let me know. Thanks.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    if (theTextField == self.textPassword) {
        [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    } else if (theTextField == self.textUsername) {
        [self.textPassword becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    // we'd better return NO here
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Swift 2.0 Version of Rob Mayoff

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == self.emailTextField {
        self.passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }else{
        self.passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The swift version could be:

```
extension LoginViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == self.emailTextField {
            passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else if textField == self.passwordTextField {
            passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried to use Esteve's answer but it doesn't work. Maybe because I'm using xib files. What I've done is change his code to make it works in my code.

It works in the same way. All you need is to assign the order value as tag, and return key according to Next or Done or Send on each input control.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    if(textField.returnKeyType==UIReturnKeyNext) {

        UITextField *next = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:textField.tag+1];
        [next becomeFirstResponder];

    } else if (textField.returnKeyType==UIReturnKeySend) {

        //Do whatever you want with the last TextField
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11128083)

Comment: if UserName has tag set to 1 and return key 'UIReturnKeyNext', and Password has tag set to 2 and return key to 'UIReturnKeySend' or 'UIReturnKeyDone', the code solves the problem, at least in a xib file.

Why does not this answer the question?

My textfields are:

- Name
- Surname
- Email
- Password
-Re-type Password.

and the codes works perfectly.