# textFieldShouldEndEditing not display Next / Done buttons keyboard

Tags: objective-c, navigation, keyboard, uitextfield

I'm not able to navigate through my form textfields with "Next" or "Done". I tried to add `UITextFieldDelegate` to my `UIViewController` and delegate my `UITextField`. I tried to modify my code according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540500/ios-app-next-key-wont-go-to-the-next-text-field) but still not work.

**UIViewController.h**

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate> {
   @property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *usernameTextfield;
   @property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *passwordTextfield;
}
```

**UIViewController.m**

```
@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize usernameTextfield, passwordTextfield;

   self.usernameTextfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,25, SCREEN_WIDTH-20, 35)];
   self.usernameTextfield.delegate = self;

   self.passwordTextfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,95, SCREEN_WIDTH-20, 35)];
   self.passwordTextfield.secureTextEntry = TRUE;
   self.passwordTextfield.delegate = self;

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
   if (textField == self.passwordTextfield) {
       [textField resignFirstResponder];
   } else if (textField == self.usernameTextfield) {
       [self.passwordTextfield becomeFirstResponder];
   }
   return YES;
}
```

Any idea will be welcomed. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fast and easy solution to manage these kind of problems : **IQKeyboardManager**

**GitHub :** https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

You'll find a demo GIF, a demo video, and a demo project on the GitHub.

Comment: I have tried this and it's fort perfectly ! Thanks !