# Can't navigate through textfields

Tags: ios, navigation, uitextfield

I want to navigate through UITextfields, but I have a problem, because nextresponder is always nil and I can't understand why. Because of that the navigation doesn't work.

I use this method:

```
  - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField {

UITableViewCell * curentCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[textField superview] superview];
NSIndexPath * indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:curentCell];

NSInteger nextTag;
if (indexPath.row == 3)
    nextTag = textField.tag + 3;
else if (indexPath.row == 6)
    nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
else if (indexPath.row == 7)
    nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
else if (indexPath.row == 8)
    nextTag = textField.tag + 2;

UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];

if (nextResponder) {
    [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
} else {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}

[self deleteBarButton];

tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);

return NO;
}
```

Here is the way I initialize the cells:

```
- (void) initCells
{
NSArray *topLevelObjectsProdus = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellProdusAsigurareHeader" owner:self options:nil];
cellHeader = [topLevelObjectsProdus objectAtIndex:0];
UIImageView * img = (UIImageView *)[cellHeader viewWithTag:1];
img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"calculator-casco.png"];

NSArray *topLevelObjectsMarca = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellAutovehicul" owner:self options:nil];
cellMasina = [topLevelObjectsMarca objectAtIndex:0];
UILabel * lblCell = (UILabel *)[cellMasina viewWithTag:2];
UIImageView * imgBgAuto = (UIImageView *)[cellMasina viewWithTag:5];
imgBgAuto.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"alege-masina-portocaliu.png"];

lblCell.textColor = [YTOUtils colorFromHexString:ColorTitlu];
lblCell.text = @"Alege masina";

NSArray *topLevelObjectsProprietar = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellPersoana" owner:self options:nil];
cellProprietar = [topLevelObjectsProprietar objectAtIndex:0];
UIImageView * imgBgProprietar = (UIImageView *)[cellProprietar viewWithTag:5];
imgBgProprietar.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"alege-masina-portocaliu.png"];
UILabel * lblCellP = (UILabel *)[cellProprietar viewWithTag:2];
lblCellP.textColor = [YTOUtils colorFromHexString:ColorTitlu];
lblCellP.text = @"Alege proprietar";

NSArray *topLevelObjectsnrKm = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellView_Numeric" owner:self options:nil];
cellNrKm = [topLevelObjectsnrKm objectAtIndex:0];
txtNumarKm = (UITextField *)[cellNrKm viewWithTag:2];
[(UILabel *)[cellNrKm viewWithTag:1] setText:@"Numar kilometri autovehicul"];
[(UITextField *)[cellNrKm viewWithTag:2] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
[YTOUtils setCellFormularStyle:cellNrKm];

NSArray *topLevelObjectsCuloare = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellView_String" owner:self options:nil];
cellCuloare = [topLevelObjectsCuloare objectAtIndex:0];
txtCuloare = (UITextField *)[cellCuloare viewWithTag:2];
[(UILabel *)[cellCuloare viewWithTag:1] setText:@"Culoare autovehicul"];
[YTOUtils setCellFormularStyle:cellCuloare];

NSArray *topLevelObjectscalc = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellCalculeaza" owner:self options:nil];
cellCalculeaza = [topLevelObjectscalc objectAtIndex:0];
UIImageView * imgBgCalculeaza = (UIImageView *)[cellCalculeaza viewWithTag:1];
imgBgCalculeaza.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"calculeaza-casco.png"];
UILabel * lblCellC = (UILabel *)[cellCalculeaza viewWithTag:2];
lblCellC.textColor = [YTOUtils colorFromHexString:ColorTitlu];
lblCellC.text = @"Cere oferta";
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should go through : [Responders](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW24)

I noticed one more thing from : [How to navigate through textfields ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347779/how-to-navigate-through-textfields-next-done-buttons) that ...

**`All "tabbable" UITextFields are on the same parent view.`**

So check for that also.

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Comment: @MariaStoica : Have you checked for the components with nextTag in your nib ?

Comment: I edited my question to show how I initialize the cells if that is what your question asks.

Comment: I succeeded by using a nsmutablearray, that i initialize with all the textfields, i want to navigate through. Thank you Bhavin Chitroda!