# How to use code from my UITextField subclass in other subclasses that have isEditing property

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, subclassing

I've got subclass of `UITextField` which add some additional functionalities when field is editing. For `UITextField` all works correclty. Now what I want is to use this piece of code in other `UIControl` subclasses that have `isEditing` property and have field to add some text. Is it possible? Or maybe one correct way is to copy-paste this code to e.g. `UITextView` class?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Couldn't you just subclass `UIControl` and then inherit from that directly for your `UITextField`'s and related classes?

Comment: But `UITextField` isn't only class subclassed from `UIControl` It has other stuff. How `UITextField` will be know about that it must be subclass of my subclass of `UIControl`? It isn't possible to create other `UITextField` class I think. Can you show me more info if it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347779/how-to-navigate-through-textfields-next-done-buttons) answer, in particular [Answerbot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257550/answerbot)'s response that details how to create a subclass of UITextField.

If you want to use the code *only* in `UITextField` controls, then you have the option of subclassing `UITextField` as described by Answerbot, for example...

```
subclassedTextField.h   (header file)
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface subclassedTextField : UITextField
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) IBOutlet UITextField *fieldPrevious;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) IBOutlet UITextField *fieldNext;
@end

subclassedTextField.m   (implementation file)
#import subclassedTextField.h
@implementation subclassedTextField
@end
```

(In this example the fieldNext & fieldPrevious properties enable "drag to associate" outlet connections from the Connection Inspector in Interface Builder, again as described by Answerbot.)

Subclassing `UIControl` or creating a Category of `UIControl` as suggested by others will allow your code to be used by other `UIControl`s, such as `UITextView`.

The benefits of creating a Category - you do not have to import the subclassed `UITextField` (`subclassedTextField` in my example) into each class where you want to implement your code. Read the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html); the section titled "Categories Add Methods to Existing Classes".

Answer (score 0):

`UITextField` inherits from `UIControl` which inherits from `UIView` which inherits from `UIResponder` which inherits from `NSObject`. So if you subclass `UIControl` you can then subclass it within your `UITextField`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a category on `UIControl`. Then all subclasses of `UIControl` would have those methods. Here is an example

```
//in .h file
@interface UIControl (Category)
- (void) testCategory;
@end

//in .m file
@implementation UIControl (Category)
- (void) testCategory
{
    //Do your stuff here
}

@end
```

Comment: Not all subclasses of `NSControl` will have an `editing` property, however.