# Is it possible to group inputs in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, tpkeyboardavoiding

I have a simple ios project that has a set of inputs like this:

[image]

currently, i use this [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) library which allows on click of an input the keyboard appears and i can click next and tab through the inputs in the following order

[image]

however i need to order it down over, like so:

[image]

currently the code just finds the next possible UITextField, i've read an example on how to navigate to the next input using tags and incrementing them, this was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347779/how-to-navigate-through-textfields-next-done-buttons).

However the above example uses the **textFieldShouldReturn** method:

`-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField; {`

which is already used in the TPKeyboardAvoiding library, i don't really want to edit or over-ride this functionality, so i was wondering if it was possible to create some kind of work around that groups each column of inputs, so when the original `textFieldShouldReturn` method finds the next possible input, it only searches in the current 'group'.

[image]

any suggestions would be great

Comment: i'd ask the tpkeyboardavoiding author. that library doesn't use anything but X and Y values for finding textfields. That would have to be modified