# UITextField resigning firstResponder too early

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder, becomefirstresponder

I have two instances of a UITextField. The `returnKeyType` of the first text field is `UIReturnKeyNext`, and the `returnKeyType` second text field is `UIReturnKeyDone`. Based of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20215571/2317675), I'm trying resign the first responder of the first text field when the 'Next' button is clicked, and then have the second text-field become the first responder. When the 'Done' button is clicked on the second text-field, the first responder is resigned, and the keyboard disappears.

Below is my code for this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == _textFieldOne){
        [_textFieldOne resignFirstResponder];
        [settingsDictionary setObject: _textFieldOne.text forKey:@"TextFieldOneInfo"];
        [settingsDictionary stringValueForKey:@"TextFieldOneInfo"];
        [self postNotificationSettingsUpdate:settingsDictionary];

        didTestPostNotificationSettings = YES;
        [_textFieldTwo becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    if (textField == _textFieldTwo){
        [_textFieldTwo resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

When the 'Next' button is clicked, the first text-field successfully resigns the first responder, and the second text-field does become the new first responder. However, the second text-field then *immediately* seems to resign it's first responder status, before the 'Done' button is clicked.

Can anyone tell me why the second text-field is resigning it's first responder status before it's 'Done' button is clicked? Thank you!

**EDIT** I've narrowed down the problem to the following line of code:

```
[self postNotificationSettingsUpdate:settingsDictionary];
```

When it's commented out, text field return-button actions behave as expected.

Comment: Are there any other events, that might cause the textfield to resign (delegates)? Where are your textfields embedded? Your code should work (event though it can be optimized as @random wrote).

Comment: Hi @croX, they are embedded inside of a table-view cell. I do have a method that sets `endEditing:YES` for the text-fields if the user clicks somewhere else on the screen...I wonder if that could be causing it? I did optimize my code thanks to @random's answer as well.

Comment: Hmm, do you perform a reload of the table view when a textfield becomes/resigns first responder?

Comment: I think I *may* have found part of the problem...there were lines inside of my if-statements that I didn't imagine had any effect on this, but apparently do. I'm going to edit my question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I believe I found a solution.

The specific offending line of code is below:

```
    [self postNotificationSettingsUpdate:settingsDictionary];
```

which calls the method below:

```
- (void)postNotificationSettingsUpdate:(NSDictionary *) updateDict {
    [self.dataCache setUserNotificationSettings:updateDict];
}
```

...which sends the the dictionary information over a network connection.

These text views are stored in a UITableView row. What appeared to me to be happening was that when this method was being called, it reloaded the view. The solution was to add calls to    `[tableView beginUpdates];` and     `[tableView endUpdates];` at the beginning and end of 
`- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField`.

After doing that, the second-text field would become the first responder when the 'Next' button of the first-text field was selected, and would resign it's first responder status when the 'Done' button was selected.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `resignFirstResponder` if you want switch textFields. I have successfully tried this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == _textFieldOne){
        [_textFieldTwo becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == _textFieldTwo){
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }

return YES;

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure who -1 voted; it wasn't me. 

I didn't realize that calling `resignFirstResponder` wasn't needed. However, my problem of textFieldTwo's first responder being resigned before the 'Done' button is clicked is still occurring.

Comment: Your answer is good remark, as you don't need to call `resignFirstResponder` on a textfield when you are about to call `becomeFirstResponder` in the first place. Still, the approach of narner has the very same effect as your solution. Therefore it won't help in this particular situation. I believe that he has some other events in play, that cause the textfieldTwo to resign its first responder status.

Comment: @narner Are you implementing any of the other `UITextField` delegate methods?

Comment: @croX Is right, I've updated my answer and added a couple lines of code

Comment: Thank you for the help! I did implement `textFieldDidBeginEditing` so that     `textField.placeholder` and `textField.text` are set to `@""`. Also, I did put a `return YES` in my code, but forgot to put that in my question. I will do so now.

Comment: Actually, you should return `NO`. Pressing the "Next" or "Done" button shouldn't add a new line character and that's what `return NO` does.