# how to identify tab key pressed in ipad app from bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: ios, ipad

I am developing one iPad application.  In that app user fill form, if user use the external bluetooth keyboard and use tab key, the order of textfield becomeFirstResponde is mismatched.

How we can identify the tab key pressed in ipad from bluetooth keyboard?
I am use reference this :https://weaklyreferenced.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/responding-to-the-tab-and-shift-tab-keys-on-ios-5-ios-6-with-an-external-keyboard/ url, but i can not get proper output. 
Please suggest something,

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347779/how-to-navigate-through-textfields-next-done-buttons

Comment: The return button is working fine and the order of textfield becomeFirstResponde is proper way.

Comment: I thought you said `the order of textfield becomeFirstResponde is mismatched` meaning that the order was wrong. So what is the problem you are having then?

Comment: Let me give you a quick example: I have four UITextFields on screen for entering simple pieces of data, and they all use my RootViewController as their UITextFieldDelegate. Every time I demo my app from the simulator I hit the tab key to advance my fields without thinking, and I’m tired of it!

Here is what happens.

Tab Order (Expected):

First
Second
Third
Fourth
Obvious, right?

Tab Order (Actual):

First
Fourth
Second
Third
So frustrating.

Comment: I'm facing same problem. But on other way if we see UITextView example and press tab key then delegate "shouldChangeTextInRange" is fired and we can check tab key with an if condition (string == "\t") but not happen in case of UITextFiled.