# textfieldshouldreturn not switching textfields

Tags: swift, uitextfield, first-responder

After looking at the examples provided by this previous question & answer...    [Switching between Text fields on pressing return key in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766896/switching-between-text-fields-on-pressing-return-key-in-swift), i figured applying the function would be relatively seamless. However, after applying the code below, the switch to a new first responder is not working. I have the delegates set, the tags set, the function set and still no progress. I'm clearly missing something in this logic but can't seem to realize what it is.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.Class1TF.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
    self.Credits1TF.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
    self.Grade1TF.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
    self.CumCredits.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
    self.CumGPA.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate

    Class1TF.tag = 0
    Credits1TF.tag = 1
    Grade1TF.tag = 2
    CumCredits.tag = 3
    CumGPA.tag = 4

    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Classes2Controller.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        // Try to find next responder
        if let nextField = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) as? UITextField {
            nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else {
            // Not found, so remove keyboard.
            Class1TF.resignFirstResponder()
            return true
        }
        // Do not add a line break
        return false
    }
```

Comment: Just add UITextFieldDelegate to your ViewController declaration

Comment: And no need to cast `self.Class1TF.delegate = self`

Comment: unfortunately, the switch is still not occuring

Comment: You need also to move your textFieldShouldReturn method out of the viewDidLoad method

Comment: I added the textfield delegate and moved the function to below the viewdidload brackets. Thank you so much, Leo!

Comment: You are welcome