# Move to next UItextfield in custom UItableViewCell (Tableview with multiple section)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, swift4

I have a `UItableView` with custom `UItableViewCell`. Each cell have `UItextField` in it. Now i want user to be able to move to next textfield by hitting next button on keyboard.
I already know that we can do following in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
cell.textField.tag =  indexPath.row
```

And then for moving to next field

```
if let nextField = self.view.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) as? UITextView {
            nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
```

**But in my case we i have multiple sections inside UItableview** so this

> cell.textField.tag =  indexPath.row

won't work. Any leads? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766896/switching-between-text-fields-on-pressing-return-key-in-swift then change UITextView to UITextField

Comment: i tried that. But wasn't helpful

Comment: `self.view.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1)` this is wrong. Try to fetch `textField` from its `superview` which is not `self.view` probably.

Comment: @TheTiger my question isn't about self.view.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1). Its about assigning tags to cells in grouped tableview

Comment: @sardarasad Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either 
 1) by taking textfield's tag as combination of section & row

```
  textfield.tag = indexPath.section*1000 + indexPath.row
```

and get it by using blow code :

```
let Row = textfield.tag % 1000
let Section = (textfield.tag - Row)/1000
```

or 
 2) You can get the section and Row value of the TableView Cell in which your textfield is, By using below code in any of textfield's delegate method :

```
let item:UITableViewCell = textField.superview?.superview as! UITableViewCell

 let indexPath = table_view.indexPath(for: item)

 print(" Section :\(indexPath?.section)")
 print(" Row :\(indexPath?.row)")
```

check the section & row value and then set textfield's becomeFirstResponder with conditions required(as per your number of section and rows)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your answer my bad i wasn't able to understand i did it by tweaking my datasource a little

```
  func getBaseValueCount(currentSection:Int) -> Int {
    var count = 0
    if currentSection == 0 {
        return count
    }
    else{
        for i in 0..<currentSection {
            count = count + (self.formSections[i].fields?.count)!
        }
    }

    return count
}
```

And then in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 cell.txtAnswer.tag = self.getBaseValueCount(currentSection: indexPath.section) + indexPath.row
```

Thanks Again.