# Tab across different custom NSCollectionViewItem cells

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview, tabbing, nscollectionviewitem

Trying to find best way of handling data entry forms in my first macOS app.
Currently trying with NSCollectionView and custom cells for different layouts, such as label + one entry field, two labels + two fields, label + date entry, etc. 
See image - Tabbing works fine through the first four cells, all the same custom cell, but then jumps to another field outside the form view. The next cell is a different custom cell, telephone number entry.
How can the tabbing be directed to the next cell in a collection view?

[image]

Comment: Hello Patrick, you need to set up the responder chain. See the link for a good start: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347779/how-to-navigate-through-textfields-next-done-buttons#1351090)

Comment: Thank you @JFS, great help. Nearly a reference manual on that link!