# Soft Keyboard in IOS Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have entries in my login page. I used ImeOptions = Unspecified in Android to focus to next entry, In last fifth entry the soft keyboard next button automatically changed as done button. In IOS i don't know how to set 
softkeyboard like android. I used the below code in my renderer.When I click next button the keyboard is hidden and not focus to next entry. Please anybody give suggestion how to fix this.

Control.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Next;

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347779/how-to-navigate-through-textfields-next-done-buttons

Comment: @ Cole Xia, I am working on xamarin forms. Any custom renderer for achieve this?

Comment: Yes, I think you can use  `EntryRenderer`