# How to override tab pressed event from external keyboard in iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to intercept/override tab pressed event and provide my custom behaviour.

Comment: please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347779/how-to-navigate-through-textfields-next-done-buttons/1351090#1351090)

Comment: @chiragshah The question clearly states it's about external keyboard

Comment: Thank you guys . My question was not clear in the beginning sorry for that. Issue is resolved now. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can override `keyCommands` property of your `UIResponder` (`UITextField`, `UITextView` etc.). You will need to write your own subclass, because `keyCommands` cannot be assigned value since it's a get-only property

```
override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? 
{
    return [UIKeyCommand(input: "\t", modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(tabPressed))]
}

@objc func tabPressed() 
{
    // do stuff
}
```