# Which delegate is called at the touch of down arrow on the keyboard?

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, uitextfielddelegate

I want to know which delegate is called on click of the down arrow on the keyboard. I was expecting the cursor to move to the securityAnswer field after the securityQuestion field. But instead it skips one textfield and goes to the third one, i.e the mobile textfield. While it works fine on click of the done button. Also, when I manually click on the securityAnswer field the down arrow dissappears and only the up arrow stays. Please see the screenshot for referance.

I have tried all the textfield delegates.

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField; 
 - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField; 
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;   
 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;    
 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;   
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField;    
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;
```

[image]

Comment: the answers [in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347779/how-to-navigate-through-textfields-next-done-buttons) may help you out...

Comment: @MichaelDautermann as I mentioned, none of the delegates are working and the link you gave suggests use of the textFieldShouldReturn delegate.

Comment: if delegates not called that's meant you doing something wrong and without code its  not possible to help

Comment: @canister_exister I meant the delegates are not getting called for the up/down button. I dont know if they are supposed to. But otherwise for everything else, like the done button, return key, tab bar etc all the delegates are working fine.