# MonoTouch change Tab oder or detect Tab to manually goto next field

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, xamarin.ios, xcode3.2

Can anyone tell me how I can change the tab order of my objects in monotouch / xCode 3? Everything I find for interface builder appears to be OS-X specific, not iOS.  If not, is there a way to detect the tab key being pressed so I can handle this myself?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There's a non-MonoTouch question about this here: [How do you set the tab order in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317417/how-do-you-set-the-tab-order-in-ios)

But I fear the answers are not what you'll like hearing :-( I was hoping for something more automatic. However the answers covers way to achieve this manually.

Comment: I have attempted that answer, which lead me to ask "or detect tab".  That answer specifically uses Enter to move to next because iOS offers an event for when enter was pressed. However I can't find a way to detect that a 'tab' key was pressed.  There is an onchanging event that iOS offers but monotouch does not seem to implement it, nor do I know if even in objective-c it would detect that tab.  Thank you though for linking me